# How can i execute two asynctask on same file?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, compression, filesize

I want to use two Asynctask on same file.
1 -> doing the compression to output filepath.
2 -> want a updated file size while 1st Asynctask is running.

How can i get this two things?

class VideoCompressor extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG,"Start video compression");
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("doInBackground: ", "0 = " + params[0] + " 1 = " + params[1]);
        return MediaController.getInstance().convertVideo(params[0],params[1]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean compressed) {
        super.onPostExecute(compressed);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(compressed){
            Log.d(TAG,"Compression successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `onProgressUpdate` method of AsyncTask, through which you can get the current progress of file compression.

Comment: in my code there is nothing like buffer or for loop so i cant get the the ProgressUpdate. I am using this code for compression https://github.com/yovenny/VideoCompress